# DataGridView override top,left header cell click (select all)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, header, selectall

I want to override the behavior of a mouse click in the DataGridView header/column cell (top, left cell).  That cell causes all rows to be selected.  Instead, I want to stop it from selecting all rows.  I see an event for RowHeaderSelect and ColumnHeaderSelect but not one for that top, left header cell.

Any ideas?  Am I just being blind?

Answer (score 5):

This is the dissasembled code of what happens when you click that cell:

```
private void OnTopLeftHeaderMouseDown()
{
    if (this.MultiSelect)
    {
        this.SelectAll();
        if (-1 != this.ptCurrentCell.X)
        {
            this.SetCurrentCellAddressCore(this.ptCurrentCell.X, this.ptCurrentCell.Y, false, false, false);
        }
    }
```

In order for you to prevent this behavior you have 2 solutions:

1. Disable multi selection (if your business logic permits)
2. Inherit your own datagrid and override `OnCellMouseDown` (something like this)

   ```
   protected override void OnCellMouseDown(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex == -1) return;
       base.OnCellMouseDown(e);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I need full row select.

The other is intriging but, unfortunately, the gridview still selected all the columns when I tried this before.  I ended up unselecting the rows as a work around but not a very pretty one.

Comment: So you did the override and the selection still happened? I did a quick test myself and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is late but hopefully it will help someone. The code below worked for me in a similar scenario.

```
    private void MyDataGridView_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView.HitTestInfo hitInfo = this.MyDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        if (hitInfo.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.TopLeftHeader)
        {
            MyDataGridView.ClearSelection();
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could gain some control over the click event using this hack :)

```
private void dataGridView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MouseEventArgs args = (MouseEventArgs)e;
    DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
    DataGridView.HitTestInfo hit = dgv.HitTest(args.X, args.Y);
    if (hit.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.TopLeftHeader)
    {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

override **OnCellMouseDown** method:

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == -1 && e.RowIndex == -1)
{
return;
}
else
{
base.OnCellMouseDown(e);
}
```