# Remove all rows selection option from datagridview topleft cell click in c#

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I am using Data Grid View control in my project and the requirement is below.
Row Headers Visible = true, Column Headers Visible = true, Multiple Select = true,
Selection Mode = Full Row Select.
Allow multiple rows selection true but do not allow to select all rows when user clicks on top left cell.

Please help me!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The top left cell's only purpose is to select all the cells, I don't think that could be disabled.

In any case you can use a if condition to check whether all the rows are selected and proceed accordingly.

ps: I am new to C# and dont know much

Comment: I am able to deselect all rows using if condition, but it's looks like a flash. When i click top left cell, in the Cell_Click() event first it selects all rows then it executes my code. It's looks like a blink. Do you have any idea to remove blink?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @anchandra response from this other [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504620/datagridview-override-top-left-header-cell-click-select-all) you may accomplish that behavior by overriding the `OnCellMouseDown` behaviour:

```
protected override void OnCellMouseDown(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex == -1) return;
    base.OnCellMouseDown(e);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the RowHeadersVisible to false.