# How to remove the top left cell in DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there a way I can remove the top left cell in a DataGrid ?

[image]

Comment: Do you just want to remove it or remove the behaviour of selecting all rows?
For the behaviour you can check here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504620/datagridview-override-top-left-header-cell-click-select-all

Comment: I would like to remove it completely

Comment: Hide it is a good solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to hide it, just set RowHeadersVisible property to false.

```
myDataGridTableStyle.RowHeadersVisible = false;
```

If you want to change the behaviour:

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504620/datagridview-override-top-left-header-cell-click-select-all)

Hope it helps

[MSDN properties for RowHeadersVisible Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridtablestyle.rowheadersvisible.aspx)