# Override OnCellMouseDown for DataGridView - type does not exist error

Tags: c#, inheritance, datagridview

I'm trying to disable the "select all cells" function that occurs when clicking the top-left header cell in the datagridview.  From another SO question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504620/datagridview-override-top-left-header-cell-click-select-all)), I am attempting to do this by inheriting a DataGridView and then overriding the OnCellMouseDown event to do nothing if the top-left cell is clicked.

**In MainForm.cs**

```
 namespace MainProjectName
 {
     public partial class MainProjectName : Form
     {
        **misc form code here**
     }
 }
```

**Then a new override DGV class was created, OverrideTest.cs**

```
 namespace MainProjectName
 {
     public partial class OverrideTest : DataGridView
     {
         protected override void OnCellMouseDown(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
         {
             if (e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex == -1) return;
             base.OnCellMouseDown(e);
         }
     }
 }
```

With this setup, the new "OverrideTest" shows up in the toolbox and I can drag my custom DataGridView onto my form successfully.  However, it fails to compile with error:

> CS0426    The type name 'OverrideTest' does not exist in the type 'MainProjectName'

**What am I doing wrong and how would you fix this type does not exist error?**

Comment: Just Curious: _e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex == -1_ `&&` or `||` ?? As to the error: Clean and Recreate the solution!

Comment: `&&`    - The upper left cell position returns as [-1, -1].  In a normal DGV with multiselect all, clicking this upper left cell selects EVERY cell in the DGV.  Clicking on a row/column header also selects that entire row/column by default, but this is easily turned off by setting the `SelectionMode` to `CellSelect`.  The `select all` behavior can only be removed via a code workaround/override.  I did try clean/rebuild, as well as deleting obj and bin folders with no luck.  Only after I made the namespace and class/form name different and THEN clean/rebuild did it work.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue.

The name used for my namespace matched the name of my main form class.

By changing the name of the main form class and all associated references, I was able to get rid of this error and make it work.